# Make newly created files in a directory automatically inherit the user and group id of the directory

Tags: permissions, users

In Linux, if I have a directory belonging to a user `user` and a group `group`, how is it possible to make it so that each time I create or move a file in the directory, this file automatically acquires the user and group of the directory it is in, irrespective of who is doing the operation?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you have setuid and setgid bits on the directory.

If those bits are set, all new files created in the directory inherit the ownership from the directory.

Please note, it is not a set in stone rule and different OS can ignore setuid and setgid on a directory. Usually, it is either obey both of them, obey just the setgid, or ignore both of them.

Comment: Thank you, White Owl. I am using Ubuntu and apparently it obeys just setgid. What OS would obey both?

Comment: Non-root users cannot change the ownership of files unless they have CAP_CHOWN assigned. DO NOT GIVE THIS CAPABILITY OUT. Simply being able to disown your own files is a great way to avoid disk quotas. Changing other user's files is a great way to break the system.

Comment: I do not intend to give this capability to my users. This would be the prerogative of the root user.